# Odoo model relationship

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I know how to make a `header->detail` relationship using the `One2many` relationship. It is pretty simple, but in the real world we need to have more complicated things than that.

In my case I have these tables.

```
Student      Homework      Paper       Test
--------------------------------------------
id           id            id          id
name         subject       title       score
```

The `Student` table has

- `one2many` to `Homework`
- `one2many` to `Paper`
- `one2many` to `Test`

and also

- `Homework` has `many2one` to `Student`
- `Paper` has `many2one` to `Student`
- `Test` has `many2one` to `Student`

Resulting in these relationships

```
Student      Homework      Paper       Test
--------------------------------------------
id           id            id          id
name         subject       title       score
homework_ids student_id    student_id  student_id
paper_ids
test_ids
```

I could make a form with `Student` model and input `Homework`, `Paper`, and `Test` from that form using the `One2many` widget.

But what if I wanted to have a form with `Homework` model where I choose a `Student` first and then input her `Homework`, but also from that form I'd like to see(or input) her other information such as `Paper`, and `Test`?

Using `Many2many` relation between `Homework`, `Paper`, and `Test` just to have the student's `Paper`, and `Test` accessible from `Homework` seems very weird to me. It also complicates the database structure, creating unnecessary `Many2many` relation.

Is there another way instead of using `Many2many` relation? I feel the database structure will be very ugly if I used that.

This is a huge concern to me as looking at Odoo as it is a heavily model dependent framework. You must start with the right model first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you have a many2one field you can create related field to show them in the current form.

Your case in homework model you can create a  related field to one2many field of paper.

```
          paper_ids = fields.One2many(related='student_id.paper_ids', readonly = True)
```

i'm assuming that your field is named paper_ids when you create a related field just keep the same type always in this case one2many field and you can remove readonly if you want the user to be able to edit the field from that form. related field are like compute field are not stored in database if you want to store the in database you must set store = True.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Do you mean to add this related field inside homework model?